# Using Dynamixel Motors on Kinetic

Tags: ros, dynamixel-motor, dynamixel-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use Dynamixel motors on ROS-kinect. I am giving this command.

```
khan@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-dynamixel-motor
```

and getting this response. I am also trying to install it on Raspberry Pi 3 in which I have installed Jessie Kinetic and having the same response which is as follows.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-dynamixel-motor
```

Your response is much appreciated. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240459/using-dynamixel-motors-on-kinetic/) by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got dynamixel package running on Kinetic. It is not in apt-get repository yet.

Just create workspace, do git clone of dynamixel repository, then catkin_make. Don't forget to add appropriate source setup.sh line to your .bashrc and restart terminal/roscore before using. It should compile without errors on Ubuntu 16.04 (tested on PC only).

Create normal worksapce:

```
~$ mkdir -p ~/my_workspace/src
~$ cd ~/my_workspace/src
~$ catkin_init_workspace
```

Clone dynamixel source code and compile:

```
~$ git clone https://github.com/arebgun/dynamixel_motor.git
~$ cd ~/my_workspace
~$ catkin_make
```

Add your new worksapce to bashrc and source it (so it is visible to roslaunch)

```
~$ echo "source ~/my_workspace/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
~$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Run your shiny new dynamixel manager:

```
~$ roslaunch dynamixel_tutorials controller_manager.launch
```

Should work on Ubuntu 16.04

---

Originally posted by [Marcin Bogdanski](https://answers.ros.org/users/26406/marcin-bogdanski/) with karma: 231 on 2016-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-08-19**:
Oh, dear could you please share the link for that clone and method. I have no idea about it. Thank you so much.

**Comment by [Marcin Bogdanski](https://answers.ros.org/users/26406/marcin-bogdanski/) on 2016-08-25**:
Hi. Sorry for late reply, I was super busy over last couple days. See edited answer

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-08-28**:
It worked. :). Thank you so Much Marcin Bogdanski.